# Rails 3 where query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I am sending an array from jquery via the url requerts to the rails controller.

when I do this in my controller

```
log_array = (params[:log_ids])
logger.debug "This is the array #{log_array.to_a}"
```

I get this in my server log

```
This is the array 85,84,83,82
```

I am trying this query to get all the selected logs:

```
@logs = Log.where(['"logs"."id" IN (?)', log_array])
```

I get this on the server log

```
SELECT "logs".* FROM "logs" WHERE ("logs"."id" IN ('85,84,83,82'))
```

It sould be like this

```
SELECT "logs".* FROM "logs" WHERE ("logs"."id" IN (85,84,83,82))
```

It seems like it puts the arry in like a string.

Is there any way to make the sql right for an array?

Comment: Is it possible that :log_ids are being set as strings? If so, I wonder if you need to call to_i on them. Although, bowsersenior has the best answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or Log.where(:id => params[:log_ids]) if you want to use where() goodness.

Answer (score 4):

You're making things too SQL-ish. Try this:

```
Log.find_all(params[:log_ids])
```

Comment: I forgot to say. This does not work. It only returns the first instance of the array.

Comment: Sorry, the correct method is `find_all`, not `find`. Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Would use the .where listed below...check out the link to the rails 3.1 deprecations.

http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface